# Invoking interface object methods

Tags: java, interface

I have a interface `Appendable` in which I have a method `appendTo(Appendable obj)`. Classes `TextMessage` and `EncMessage` extend class `Message`, which implements `Appendable`.In `TextMessage` I have to implement method `appendTo(Appendable obj)`    so that if `obj` is an instance of `TextMessage` the method is supposed to change its data members. But I can't access `TextMessage` set methods.So my question is how can I access and use them?

Comment: It's nice to explain it in words but for sooner help please share a minimal testable code to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement appendTo of TextMessage like this :

```
void appendTo (Appendable obj) {
  if (obj instanceof TextMessage) {
    TextMessage msg = (TextMessage) obj;
    msg.setXXX (...);
    ...
  }
}
```

I had to make some assumptions without actually seeing your code.

Comment: Sorry for not posting any code, I thought that explaining it in a few words would make it more clear.Anyways, thank you, your solution works just fine!